# Eclipse debugging for null pointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` as shown below.

However, the debugger is not able to bring it up when enabled in this method, the code is getting invoked with reflections. Can you please provide me ideas\techniques to be able to debug this code?

---

```
[10/18/16 18:20:47:933 EST] 00000051 DWLExceptionU E   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager$NotificationChannel.notify(NotificationManager.java:662)
    at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager$NotificationType.notify(NotificationManager.java:402)
    at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:1454)
    at com.dwl.base.notification.bean.impl.NotificationBean.notify(NotificationBean.java:142)
    at com.dwl.base.notification.EJSLocalCSLNotification_e2801c59.notify(EJSLocalCSLNotification_e2801c59.java)
    at com.dwl.base.notification.EJSProxy$$NotificationLocal.notify(Unknown Source)
    at au.com.xxxxx.mdm.notification.NotificationHelper.sendNotification(NotificationHelper.java:75)
    at au.com.xxxxxx.mdm.behaviour.SingleCustomerViewId.triggerNotification(SingleCustomerViewId.java:159)
    at au.com.xxxxxxx.mdm.behaviour.SingleCustomerViewId.execute(SingleCustomerViewId.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.dwl.base.extensionFramework.JavaExtensionSet.invoke(JavaExtensionSet.java:159)
    at com.dwl.base.extensionFramework.ExtensionHandler.executeExtension(ExtensionHandler.java:251)
    at com.dwl.base.DWLCommonComponent.handleExtensions(DWLCommonComponent.java:1380)
    at com.dwl.base.DWLCommonComponent.postExecute(DWLCommonComponent.java:509)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.common.TCRMCommonComponent.postExecute(TCRMCommonComponent.java:263)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.coreParty.component.TCRMPersonComponent.addPerson(TCRMPersonComponent.java:1641)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.coreParty.component.TCRMPartyComponent.addPerson(TCRMPartyComponent.java:3079)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.coreParty.component.TCRMPartyComponent.addPartySimple(TCRMPartyComponent.java:2813)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.coreParty.component.TCRMPartyComponent.addParty(TCRMPartyComponent.java:2471)
    at com.dwl.tcrm.coreParty.controller.TCRMCorePartyTxnBean.addPerson(TCRMCorePartyTxnBean.java:1764)
    at Proxy5aa32899_c04f_46c5_9706_69af241cd3c4.addPerson(Unknown Source)
    at Proxy5aa32899_c04f_46c5_9706_69af241cd3c4.addPerson(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLTxnBP.processPersistentObject(DWLTxnBP.java:262)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLTxnBP.execute(DWLTxnBP.java:115)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLTxnProcessor.processTx(DWLTxnProcessor.java:98)
    at com.dwl.unifi.tx.manager.CTxRxFacade.processTxNormal(CTxRxFacade.java:681)
    at com.dwl.unifi.tx.manager.CTxRxFacade.processTx(CTxRxFacade.java:544)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLRequestHandler.processTransaction(DWLRequestHandler.java:1187)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLRequestHandler.processTx(DWLRequestHandler.java:591)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.DWLServiceControllerBase.processRequest(DWLServiceControllerBase.java:253)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.beans.EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d.processRequest(EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d.java)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.beans._EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d_Tie.processRequest(_EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d_Tie.java:1)
    at com.dwl.base.requestHandler.beans._EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemoteCSLDWLServiceController_2c54996d_Tie.java)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: Is `NotificationHelper` your class?

Comment: If you could post the code of `NotificationManager.NotificationChannel.notify()` method and point where is the line 662 it would be helpful

Comment: @Sergi I think that's an external library. At least when looking up `com.dwl.base.notification` package, that's what I found

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, you are right. Then it will be nice to see at least code of `NotificationHelper`

Comment: yes, indeed its an external library

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please provide me ideas\techniques to be able to debug this code?

Since you said the method is called from reflection, you can see that in the stacktrace.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
```

So, keep reading up from that.

I'm guessing you intentionally edited the `xxxx` values, so these are your libraries that are being dynamically called.

```
at au.com.xxxxx.mdm.notification.NotificationHelper.sendNotification(NotificationHelper.java:75)
at au.com.xxxxxx.mdm.behaviour.SingleCustomerViewId.triggerNotification(SingleCustomerViewId.java:159)
at au.com.xxxxxxx.mdm.behaviour.SingleCustomerViewId.execute(SingleCustomerViewId.java:129)
```

Then, the rest of the call stack just goes through some other code library within the same package.

```
at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager$NotificationChannel.notify(NotificationManager.java:662)
at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager$NotificationType.notify(NotificationManager.java:402)
at com.dwl.base.notification.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:1454)
at com.dwl.base.notification.bean.impl.NotificationBean.notify(NotificationBean.java:142)
at com.dwl.base.notification.EJSLocalCSLNotification_e2801c59.notify(EJSLocalCSLNotification_e2801c59.java)
at com.dwl.base.notification.EJSProxy$$NotificationLocal.notify(Unknown Source)
```

So, the problem definitely starts at `NotificationHelper.sendNotification(NotificationHelper.java:75)`, but it cannot easily be determined the path that the code took in order to reach its eventual destination or what exactly caused the exception without inspecting the source of `(NotificationManager.java:662)`